# Null reference error in SSIS package when using redirect

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I am working on a product that allows users to create and perform various actions with SSIS packages and I want to be able to support versions of SQL Server  2012, 2014, and 2016 Client Tools. Previously, we supported SQL Server 2012 (version 11.0.0.0) Client Tools and would require our users to install the SQL Server 2012 Client Tools, regardless of the version of SQL Server they were using.

I want to be able to remove the requirement for users to have to install 2012 Client Tools but have been running into a null reference issue. I can compile the project against a given SQL version and the code works great when that version exists on the user's system. If I then try running the project on a system with a different SQL version using an assembly binding redirect in the config file, I get a null reference error.

The NULL reference occurs when the host.InnerObject is cast to MainPipe. The next line causes a null reference when trying to access the ComponentMetaDataCollection. I've checked the MainPipe class documents for 2012->2016 and there do not seem to be any obvious differences in the structure of the class from version to version that should cause the cast to fail.

In the example below I have compiled against 2012 (v11) and redirected to 2016 (v13) but I have tried all combinations using the 3 different versions:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;

namespace TestConsole
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            Console.WriteLine("Test started at {0}", DateTime.Now);
            sw.Start();

            TestMinimumPackageTest();

            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("\nTest completed at {0}", DateTime.Now);
            Console.WriteLine("Total Elapsed Time: {0}", sw.Elapsed);
            Console.WriteLine("\nPress Enter to exit.");
            Console.Read();
        }

        static void TestMinimumPackageTest()
        {
            string selectCommand = "Select [IDColumn] From [dbo].[TestTable]";

            string targetTable = "TestTable";
            Package package = new Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Package();
            var task = new DataFlowSelect();

            TaskHost host = package.Executables.Add("STOCK:PipelineTask") as TaskHost;
            task.MainPipe = host.InnerObject as MainPipe;

            IDTSPipeline100 pipeline = task.MainPipe;

            IDTSComponentMetaData100 adapter = task.MainPipe.ComponentMetaDataCollection.New();

        }
    }
    public class DataFlowSelect
    {
        public DataFlowSelect() { }
        public IDTSPipeline100 MainPipe { get; set; }
        public string SourceObject { get; set; }
        public string TargetObject { get; set; }
        public Package Package { get; set; }
        public bool CreateTarget { get; set; }
        public Hashtable ColumnMappings { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the App.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup> 
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect  oldVersion="11.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect  oldVersion="11.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.PipelineHost" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect  oldVersion="11.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS" publicKeyToken="89845dcd8080cc91" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect  oldVersion="11.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: have you used the debugger.. you probably not properly creating an Instance of some object

Comment: I used the debugger in both a successful run (no redirect) and unsuccessful run (using redirect) and the only difference seems to be that the cast fails. The other objects look the same.